# Django messages framework not working in template loop

Tags: django, django-middleware, django-1.3, django-context

I recently upgraded to Django 1.3 and I want to start using the Messages system.

I have added my Middleware, Template context processors and also messages into the `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
    'facebook.djangofb.FacebookMiddleware',
    'annoying.middlewares.RedirectMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.auth",
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.messages',
)
```

I'm simply just testing based on a view that makes a simple calculation.

in the admin, the messages show up, however when trying to render them in my base.html file I get the following error.

```
Caught TypeError while rendering: 'module' object is not iterable
```

and in the stack it fails here.

```
{% for message in messages %}
```

I have also removed the for statement and the I still get the following error, nothing more

```
<module 'django.contrib.messages' from '/Users/ApPeL/.virtualenvs/mysite.com/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/__init__.py'>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Last time something like this happened to me, there was a problem in my view. So to quote DrTyrsa, show your view.

Comment: did you get solution to this issu am also stuck with this issue

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this problem. I had included the following in my context processor:

```
from django.contrib import messages
...
def allrequests(request):
    ctx = {
        ...
        'messages': messages
    }
    return ctx
```

Make sure you are not setting `messages` in the context, as it is set in the correct manner by `django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages`.

Answer (score -1):

How did you MIDDLEWWARE_CLASSES and TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py, it must look like :

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
   "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
   "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
   "django.core.context_processors.request",
   "django.core.context_processors.media",
   "django.core.context_processors.static",
   "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
)
```

And in INSTALLED_APPS :

```
'django.contrib.messages'
```

And in your template (did you forgot the if? ):

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
 {% endif %}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Copy and pasted my configuration, also tried moving some items around, still no luck

Comment: Are you using {% if messages %} in your template view?